# Duplicated items using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to insert elements from a list in my database using node and mongoose. The list contains just url as strings. Before inserting it checks if the url is already in the database for a user. "person" is a document and links is an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
          var found = false;
          //if no links
          if (person.links.length === 0) {
            person.links.push({link: url[i]});
            person.save(function (err) {
              if (err) return handleError(err);
            });
          }
          else{
            //for each link in database
            for (var z = 0; z < person.links.length; z++) {
              //If we find it change status
              if (url[i] === person.links[z].link) {
                found = true;
                break;
              }
            }
            //If we have not found it
            if (found === false)
            {
              //Save it
              person.links.push({link: url[i]});
              person.save(function (err) {
                if (err) return handleError(err);
              });
            }
          }
```

But it generates duplicate elemts and I don't understand why:

```
"links" : [
        {
            "link" : "google.es",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57d15ed8b9859615ef11e8b6"),
        },
        {
            "link" : "gog.com",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57d15ed8b9859615ef11e8b7"),
        },
        {
            "link" : "google.es",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57d15ed8b9859615ef11e8b6"),
        },
        {
            "link" : "gog.com",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57d15ed8b9859615ef11e8b7"),
        }
    ],
```

Furthermore the _id is repeated for the same url so I don't know if it is my fault or that something is not working right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array operator **[`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)** is competent to the task enough. It adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case **[`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)** does nothing to that array.

The only task you have to do is preprocess the `url` array into an array of documents similar to the `links` embedded schema in `Person`. Use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** to tranform the array.

Consider the following operation which exactly the same thing albeit more efficiently:

```
var links = url.map(function(u){ return { "link": u }; });
person.update(
    { "_id": personId },
    { "$addToSet": { "links": { "$each": links } } },
    function(err, result) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log(result);
    }
);
```

or just use the Mongoose's **[`addToSet()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.addToSet)** method:

```
var links = url.map(function(u){ return { "link": u }; });
console.log(person.links)

// call the addToSet function using the array with apply()
var added = person.links.addToSet.apply(this, links);

console.log(person.links);
console.log(added);
```

Comment: When using addToSet() I get the following error: events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.map (native)
    at addToSet (/home/yabir/code/js/bot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:621:25)
    at /home/yabir/code/js/bot/index.js:119:43
    at /home/yabir/code/js/bot/node_modules/mongoose-find-one-or-create/index.js:15:17
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/yabir/code/js/bot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3336:16)
    at /home/yabir/code/js/bot/node_modules/kareem/index.js:259:21